# reloading tableview causing crash

Tags: objective-c, ios

Hello all i'm writing ios app that has tableview with data and searchbar
when i make search get result from server then i parse it then i reload tableview with new content then it crash with this error

```
Assertion failure in -[UITableView _endCellAnimationsWithContext:], /SourceCache/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-2372/UITableView.m:862
2012-12-11 11:52:54.108 Mazadqatr[15903:c07] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'attempt to delete row 0 from section 0 which only contains 0 rows before the update'
```

Comment: I think the issue is with your numberofrowsinsection. Please check that delegate and cellForRowAtIndexPath delegate

Answer (score 0):

Your `UITableView` first `section` is having no rows, but you are trying to do some deletions there. Check your `datasource` of `UITableView` in your `viewcontroller`.

Comment: no table hasn't any section and i didn't delete from it i just [self.tableView reloadData];

Comment: check `numberofrowsinsection` returning value or not